# How to dynamically parse and transform post/page content before displaying it?

Tags: posts, pages, hooks

I have several posts where part of the displayed content will depend on several conditions.
I am thinking on creating a custom html tag. Then, before displaying the post content,
the conditions will be checked by running a script in the background . Finally  the appropriate content will be displayed by replacing the tag with data retrieved from a database.

What is the best way to do this pre-processing with wordpress? Are they specific hooks allowing to get access to the post before displaying it?

example:

TEXT

custom html

TEXT

Comment: Use this filter: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/

Comment: @shanebp Thanks! Do you know a better way than embedding custom html for my problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the classic editor, then a [custom shortocode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) is a good option. Although shortcodes can be used with the block editor the more modern way would be to create a [custom (dynamic) block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/).

You can insert the shortcode / block to the post content when needed and have the callback handle any necessary logic and rendering.

If you prefer, you could also use [the_content filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/), which lets you modify the post's content, as a string, before it is rendered - *assuming you're using [the_content()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) in your [Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) or otherwise applying the filter to the post content.*